# How to increase aws elastic beanstalk request body size?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have an application running on elb and I am having the error 413 when I upload files with more than 1MB.
I added .ebextensions\nginx\conf.d\proxy.conf and .platform\nginx\conf.d\custom.conf in my project root directory and the error is still happening.

Inside the file proxy.conf and custom.conf there is only the line **client_max_body_size 50M;**.

Comment: What EB platform you use?

Comment: @Marcin I am using tomcat, and my application is written in java, html, javascript and css.

Comment: I mean, specific version, e.g. `64bit Amazon Linux 2 v4.1.7 running Tomcat 8.5 Corretto 11 `?

Comment: @Marcin sorry about that, it's Tomcat 8.5 with Corretto 11 running on 64bit Amazon Linux 2